Sum of the vectors from centre $O$ to the polygon vertices
I'm attempting to calculate the sum of the vectors from the center of a regular polygon to each of the vertices. I have already solve it in a complex analysis manner:
To represent the vertices of a regular polygon using polar coordinates, we define the vertices as follows:
$$
A_i=\left(\cos\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{i-1}{n}\right),\,\sin\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{i-1}{n}\right)\right),\;i\in\{1,\, \cdots ,n\}
$$
To calculate the sum $\sum \vec{A_i}\,$,we need to evaluate the sums $\sum \cos\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{i-1}{n}\right)$ and $\sum \sin\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{i-1}{n}\right)$. These can be expressed using complex exponentials as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{j=1}^n \cos\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{j-1}{n}\right) &=
 Re\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \exp\left(2\pi i\cdot\frac{j-1}{n}\right)\right) \\
 &= Re\left(\frac{1-\left[\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\right]^n}
     {1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)}\right) = 0 \\
 \sum_{j=1}^n \sin\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{j-1}{n}\right) &=
 Im\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \exp\left(2\pi i\cdot\frac{j-1}{n}\right)\right) \\
 &= Im\left(\frac{1-\left[\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\right]^n}
     {1-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)}\right) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the sum of the vectors to each of the vertices of the polygon is $\vec{0}$.
However, I'm just wondering that is there any geometric method to solve this problem? (Maybe the symmetric property of regular polygons?)

Whatever the sum is, it must be invariant under rotation by $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ radians around the center. There is only one such point...

The beautiful power of symmetry arguments, it literally brings me joy.
